# Refactorizar código en C#

Tags: c#, .net

Estoy intentando refactorizar el siguiente código, pero no logro realizarlo. El problema radica en la cantidad de código que se repite ya sea que se cumpla o no la condición del if, ya que solo cambia una parte del Where y el resto de código es igual repitiendose en las distintas opciones del if.

Si se cumple la condición del if:

```
&& (!k.WorkOrderTab.Code.Equals("DOC-ASSET") || (k.WorkOrderTab.Code.Equals("DOC-ASSET") && workOrder.CMDB_ID != null))
                   && k.TemplateTab != true
```

Si no se cumple la condición del if:

```
&& (!k.WorkOrderTab.Code.Equals("DOC-ASSET") || (k.WorkOrderTab.Code.Equals("DOC-ASSET")))
                    && k.TemplateTab.Equals(true)
```

Este es el codigo a refactorizar:

```
            List<object> Tabs = null;

            if (!isPlantilla)
            {
                Tabs = op.OpContractWorkOrderTab
               .Where(k => k.Enabled
                   && k.WoTab.Enabled
                   && (!k.WoTab.Code.Equals("DOC-ASSET") || (k.WoTab.Code.Equals("DOC-ASSET") && workOrder.CMDB_ID != null))
                   && k.TemplateTab != true)
               .Select(k => new
               {
                   TabLabel = k.Label,
                   FixexOrder = k.FixedOrder,
                   k.Order
               })
               .OrderByDescending(k => k.FixexOrder)
               .OrderBy(k => k.Order)
               .ToList<object>();
            }
            else
            {
                Tabs = op.OpContractWorkOrderTab
                .Where(k => k.Enabled
                    && k.Woab.Enabled
                    && (!k.WoTab.Code.Equals("DOC-ASSET") || (k.WoTab.Code.Equals("DOC-ASSET")))
                    && k.TemplateTab.Equals(true)
                )
                .Select(k => new
                {                      
                    TabLabel = k.Label,
                    FixexOrder = k.FixedOrder,
                    k.Order
                })
                .OrderByDescending(k => k.FixexOrder)
                .OrderBy(k => k.Order)
                .ToList<object>();
            }
```

Por su ayuda muchas gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mover el `isPlantilla` dentro del `Where` debería funcionar

```
Tabs = op.OpContractWorkOrderTab
.Where(k => k.Enabled && k.WoTab.Enabled
 && (
 !k.WoTab.Code.Equals("DOC-ASSET") || 
 (k.WoTab.Code.Equals("DOC-ASSET") && (isPlantilla ? true : workOrder.CMDB_ID != null)))
   && k.TemplateTab != true)
.Select(k => new
{
    TabLabel = k.Label,
    FixexOrder = k.FixedOrder,
    k.Order
})
.OrderByDescending(k => k.FixexOrder)
.OrderBy(k => k.Order)
.ToList<object>();
```